Can I shoot short films on a tourist visa in the UK?
Can I shoot a short on tourist visa?
I saw this under the immigration rules: PA.14.3. Film crew (actor, producer, director or technician) employed by an overseas company may visit the UK to take part in a location shoot for a film or programme or other media content that is produced and financed overseas.

Note: also the genre may affect the visa (if it go in direction of journalism). But I think the PA14.3 is what you are: your food, stay, time is financed by you as overseas citizen and overseas money. -- but in general your question may require legal advice (my opinion: youtubers/tiktokers may get much money on documenting they travel in UK) and i doubt they go with visa.

Are you employed by an overseas company, or self-employed? If the latter you would be working, which is not allowed under PA14.3 as quoted in your question.

The legal answer to this is quite murky.  But in practice, if it's just you and a camera shooting scenery in natural light, it's highly unlikely anybody would care, and in the unlikely event that they did, it would difficult to prove that this is "work" as opposed to you recording your holiday.
It's a sliding scale though, and the more "professional" your shoot gets (actors, lighting, staging, other cameras), the more work-like it becomes.

(+1) Also the more time spent doing it out of the total length of stay.
